# Removing the .aspx extension from the web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am new to URLRewriting and trying to remove the .aspx extension using the following script in my web.config

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
     <section name="rewriteModule" type="RewriteModule.RewriteModuleSectionHandler, RewriteModule"/>
  </configSections>
 <connectionStrings>

<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
           <rule name="Redirect to clean URL" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^([a-z0-9/]+).aspx$" ignoreCase="true"/>
          <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}"/>
          </rule>
     </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

However, I have no success with this. Moreover, the following code block is giving me an error.

```
 <httpHandlers>
       <add verb="*" path="*.aspx" 
            type="URLRewriter.RewriterFactoryHandler, URLRewriter" />
 </httpHandlers>

> Could not load file or assembly 'URLRewriter' or one of its
> dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Do I need to add the rewrite engine to my web application?

I have gone through [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974#urlrewriting_topic3) but I could not get it.

Can any one suggest to me a step by step process or sample script please?

Comment: If you're using VS 2010 then you could use Routing instead, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx

Comment: I am using visual studio 2008 with IIS 6.0

Answer (score 1):

Use the following rule, works like a charm everytime!

```
<rule name="san aspx">
  <!--Removes the .aspx extension for all pages.-->
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some nice rewritting engine with how-to's :)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2538/URL-Rewriting-with-ASP-NET

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_framework/article.php/c19535/RewriteNET--A-URL-Rewriting-Engine-for-NET.htm

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have not added the dll Reference in the Web project for the class URLRewriter. Add this reference to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

(As alternatives to writing your own)

IIS 7 URL rewrite module :

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=7435

IIS 5/6 :

http://iirf.codeplex.com/